# Unfold nested dictionary with lists into pandas DataFrame - keys column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to unfold nested dictionary, where first key is ID. I am able to do it within a simple loop, however I expect there should be more "pythonic" solution.

```
example_dict = {'W.00': {'name': ['C10', 'C11'],
                         'value': [1, 2]},
                'W.01': {'name': ['C98', 'C99', 'C100'],
                         'value': [11, 10, 12]},
                'W.03': {'name': ['C57', 'C60', 'C60'],
                         'value': [33, 32, 35]}
               }
```

My code:

```
empty = pd.DataFrame()     
for id in example_dict.keys():
    temp_frame= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dict[id])
    temp_frame['id'] = id
    empty = pd.concat([empty, temp_frame], ignore_index=True)
```

Expected output:

```
id    name  value 
W.00  C10   1
W.00  C11   2
W.01  C98   11
W.01  C99   10
W.01  C100  22
W.03  C57   33
W.03  C60   32
W.03  C61   35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension with concat:

```
(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v) for v in example_dict.values()], 
           keys=example_dict.keys() )
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
      name  value
W.00   C10      1
W.00   C11      2
W.01   C98     11
W.01   C99     10
W.01  C100     12
W.03   C57     33
W.03   C60     32
W.03   C60     35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `explode`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(example_dict).T
df=pd.concat([s['name'].explode(),s['value'].explode()],axis=1)
df
Out[521]: 
      name value
W.00   C10     1
W.00   C11     2
W.01   C98    11
W.01   C99    10
W.01  C100    12
W.03   C57    33
W.03   C60    32
W.03   C60    35
```